# How to create shortcut of a button on a panel at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, panel

I have a panel that contains a lot of buttons(right panel). I want to add a shortcut of selected button to another panel(left panel) with the same properties and events dynamically at runtime.
Buttons have so many properties like image, text, backcolor, forecolore, ... etc.

[image: App Design]

Also the buttons will open new form inside main panel:

```
private void butntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.main_panel.Controls.Clear();
    Form1 myForm = new Form1();
    myForm.TopLevel = false;
    myForm.AutoScroll = true;
    this.main_panel.Controls.Add(myForm);
    myForm.Show();
}
```

How Can i create a shortcut on left panel?

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227969/how-to-clone-a-windows-forms-controls-even-with-non-serializable-properties

Comment: Since 'shortcut' is a term used in menues and buttons your title is rather misleading. Looks like you do want want to create a shortcut but want an easy way to create a copy, aka clone..?

Comment: If you really find that all those properties are too much to copy you should consider making a button class you can reuse; hook it to the same event and you're done.. Or write a buttonClone factory function.

Comment: Control cloned1 = CloneControl(button8); 
This will make this error:
Error CS0103 The name 'CloneControl' does not exist in the current 
or
Button leftpannelbutton = new Button(); leftpannelbutton = button1.Clone();
this will make this error:
Error CS1061 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Clone' and no extension method 'Clone' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There is no builtin `Clone` method for control. You need to implement one, yourself.

Comment: There is no practical way to clone a control, way too many properties.  But it is not a problem, you have code somewhere that created that control.  Just run it again.  If it is buried in the InitializeComponent() method then you do have to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a clone method which accepts a button as input and creates another button based on the input button's properties, also handle click event of the cloned button and just call [`PerformClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method of the input button:

```
public Button Clone(Button input)
{
    var output = new Button();
    output.Text = input.Text;
    // do the same for other properties that you need to clone
    output.Click += (s,e)=>input.PerformClick();
    return output;
}
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
var btn = Clone(button1);
panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Also instead of a panel, it's better to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`, so you don't need to handle the location and the layout yourself.

**Note:** If it's a dynamic UI and users can reorder command buttons or create whatever you called shortcut, the probably for the next step you may need to store the status of the panel to be able to reload buttons at the next load of the application after the application closed. In this case it's better to consider a pattern like command pattern. Then you can have your commands as classes. The then you can say which button is responsible to run which command at run-time and you can simply store the relation between buttons and commands using their names.

Comment: I use flowlayoutpanel. the button. How Can I store the status?

Comment: It's quite broad. As I told you as an example, let's say you have some commands named "Save", "Load", "New", "Print". Then it's enough to store some information about the relation between these commands and your buttons. For example you can say "button1" runs "Save", "button2" runs "Print", and so on. When you can describe something using strings, it mean you can store such information in a database of a file. And load it again and use it. Finding a control using its name is easy. Running a method using its name is easy too.

Comment: I have a little problem now. I don't want to add button more than once inside my left panel. what should i do? i'd tried this in button clone method but this won't work:
            foreach (Button b in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                if (!b.Text.ToLower().Contains(input.Text.ToLower()))
                {

                 }
            }

Comment: It's not the responsibility of clone method. You have a lot of options to stop creating duplicate shortcuts. For example, you can have a `List<string>` and add the `Name` property of the button which you are cloning to the list. Then always before clone, check if the list contains the button name, it mean you have already cloned it. As another solution you can set something in the `Tag` property of the button which you are going to clone. This way, you can prevent cloning of the buttons which they tag already have value.

Comment: I have a new problem. when i drag and drop control inside the flowlayoutpanel with this:
[MSDN Social](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c383ef0b-51b9-489c-9b54-398948e5acaa/how-to-move-controls-at-runtime-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control?forum=csharpgeneral)
the clone button event, won't work anymore.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question sharing a [MCVE] to let the users reproduce the problem. Then they can help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271796/how-to-troubleshoot-creating-clone-control-event-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Create class Button like so

Button leftpannelbutton = new Button();
leftpannelbutton = button1.Clone();

Now leftpannelbutton is eqaul to button1. Now just add that to your form.

Find Below ( Reflection)

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T controlToClone) 
        where T : Control
    {
        PropertyInfo[] controlProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in controlProperties)
        {
            if (propInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                if(propInfo.Name != "WindowTarget")
                    propInfo.SetValue(instance, propInfo.GetValue(controlToClone, null), null);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the `.Clone()` method come from? I've never seen it on a Windows Control.

Comment: Nor has the compiler.

Comment: Control cloned1 = CloneControl(button8); 
This will make this error:
Error CS0103 The name 'CloneControl' does not exist in the current 
or
Button leftpannelbutton = new Button(); leftpannelbutton = button1.Clone();
this will make this error:
Error CS1061 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Clone' and no extension method 'Clone' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please see edited post for explanation. Hope this helps